# iOS App resolution - AIR

Tags: ios, ipad

I have just completed an iOS app for iPad using AIR and AS3 however Apple rejected it due to the app appearing in the top left only taking up a 1/4 of the screen. I am assuming because they have tested using iPad with retina display. I didn't develop the app for retina so is there any way to still use the same code and assets for both normal and retina?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572116/programming-tips-to-optimize-flash-air-for-ios-retina-displays

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to not allow the app to be used on retina devices?

Comment: No, but you dont really want that anyway, lots of ret devices out there now.